# trying to save time with PHP if/elseif statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a rather big if statement:

```
if (!$result_spam)
{
$confrim_spam = "FAILED";

}
else if ($result_spam)
{
$confrim_spam = "PASSED";
}

if (!$result_email_manage)
{
$confrim_email_manage = "FAILED";

}
else if ($result_email_manage)
{
$confrim_email_manage = "PASSED";
}

if (!$result_analyt)
{
$confrim_analytics = "FAILED";
}

else if ($result_analyt)
{
$confrim_analytics = "PASSED";
}
```

Now I want to do another if statement to check if all have PASSED or if all have FAILED or is some have PASSED and some have FAILED and then echo (do something with) the failed ones.

I know how to check if all have passed or failed:

```
if ($confirm_spam == "PASSED" AND $confirm_analytics == "PASSED"
```

but to check if some have passed and some haven't and then find the ones that failed will take too long, right?

I was just wondering, would there be an easier/quicker way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are all bools anyway:

```
if($result_spam && $result_email_manage && $result_analyt){
    //do all passed
}
elseif($result_spam || $result_email_manage || $result_analyt){
   //at least one passed
   if(!$result_spam){ echo '$result_spam failed';}
   if(!$result_email_manage){ echo '$result_email_manage failed';}
   if(!$result_analyt){ echo '$result_analyt failed';}
}
else {
   //do all failed
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think i didn't explain my situation properly. I know how to check if they all pass and if they all don't and i also know how to check if some passed and some didn't. But i don't know how to see which ones didn't pass (when checking if some passed and some didn't)

Answer (score 1):

You can change validation logic to something like

```
$passed = array();
$failed = array();
if (!$result_spam)
{
   array_push($failed, "confirm_spam");
}
else
{
   array_push($passed, "confirm_spam");
}
...
```

Then you have an easy and clear way to check whether all passed/failed and which tests are failed.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try this way:

```
$passed = $failed = "";

$all = array("confrim_spam" => $result_spam,
             "confrim_email_manage" => $result_email_manage,
             "confrim_analytics" => $result_analyt);


foreach($all as $a => $b)
{
    if (!$b)
        $failed.= $a . ", ";
    else
        $passed.= $a . ", ";
}
```

Then if var `$passed` is empty, none passed else if `$failed` is not empty, at last one have not passed.. so do you got what passed and what failed and do something with them. And you can store results both in a string or an array whatever you want...

Comment: Beat me to it :-P this would scale as more options are added.